# COUNTIF not working with string "True" or "False"

Tags: google-sheets, countif

I have this very simple columns of either string `True` or `False`.

I am trying to use this formula `= COUNTIF(F2:F, "True")` to get the number of `True` in the column. But its not working. It works with other strings such as `apples`, but never with `True` or `False`.

[image]

**How do you compare that?**

Comment: This emulates the Microsoft Excel behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try:

```
=countif(F2:F,"'"&"True")
```

(Or better still, avoid `True` and `False` as Text.)

Comment: Seems like Google's types are loose or something of the sort.

Answer (score 4):

Adding a wildcard at the end of the string seems to work well for both true and false text strings.

```
=COUNTIF(F2:F13,"Tru*")
```

However it runs the risk of matching unwanted strings, for example the text string TrueThat would be matched by "Tru*"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (where COUNTIF would not register the TRUE within a formula produced range)...the problem was caused by writing TRUE and FALSE with quotation marks around them in the original formula where they were the outcome value, e.g., =IF(AND(DATE(2022,7,15)-$Q2>90,[@[DATE REVIEWED]]<>"",[@REFERENCE]="CORSTRR"),"TRUE","FALSE").

As you probably already know, TRUE & FALSE do not require quotation marks in formulas where they are used to show the outcome value.
HOWEVER, to count the buggers you have to use quotation marks in the COUNTIF function.
So, in short: no quotes around TRUE and FALSE in formulas where they are the outcomes, though use quotes where you are trying to count them (where they're not the outcomes per se).